# installing theme on laravel 5.6 on existed laravel

Tags: laravel

`sb-admin-laravel-5-master` theme is trying set up on my existed `laravel` project.

I have copied `resources/view/` to my **existed laravel project** at `resources/view/`.

but problem is not working `css` or other stuffs as in theme and console has error

> Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost/test1/ytl/public/assets/scripts/frontend.js”.

[image]

**also done scripts folder:**
[image]

Comment: the css and javascript must be in the public folder. maybe you might compile the webpack to setup it. the template have docs? if so provide it

Comment: did you ran gulp?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use Gulp (gulpfile.js in your root folder) in your project, go to the root folder and run `gulp` in your console.

If you use Webpack (webpack.mix.js in your root folder), go to the root folder and run `npm run dev` in your console.

Of course in your gulpfile.js/webpack.mix.js-file there must be a copy command in it so it copies something from `resources/assets/js/*` to `public/scripts/*`.

For the gulpfile.js it would look similar to this:

```
mix.copy('resources/assets/js', 'public/build/js');
```

Comment: how did you know he did not run gulp? nice way to get points by reading comments! :)

Comment: @JoseSilva ,Just create your answer Mate , the devs know Who has right :')

Comment: @JoseSilva How do you know he did run gulp? Nothing in his question indicates it. So I've gone with both possible solutions: Gulp until Laravel 5.3, Webpack from Laravel 5.4 onwards. Also I've noted that some sort of copy command should be in those files, so he'll get a clue where to look at if he already had run gulp/webpack. I have provided a clear answer to get him towards the right direction. Feel free to do the same ;)